# About the orthogonal projection.

Tags: geometry, vectors

[image]

The projection

$$Proj_{\vec{AC}}\vec{AB}$$

Yields the vector that corresponds to the line.

I am unsure, however:

- Is it necessary for $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{AC}$ to be adjacent? All the examples I see, they are, but dunno.
- Does the length of $\vec{AC}$ have any sort of impact in the result? From what I gather, $\vec{AC}$ is used merely to describe the angle so that the projection can be calculated.
- When it comes to orthogonal projection, the examples always use localised arrows ($\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{AC}$) - *must* that be the case? What happens if you do it with two points $X$ and $Y$ in space instead? (I don't see any reason to do so, but just curious).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Projection is defined on vectors. Vectors have a magnitude and direction (think of them like displacements); the position of the base of the arrow has no meaning. Thus, it's meaningless to say that $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{AC}$ are adjacent.
- The length of $\vec{AC}$ has no impact on the final vector from the projection.
- Again, projection is defined on *vectors*, what you call "localized arrows". It doesn't mean anything to project one position on another.

Comment: Thank you, regarding the first point, would $$Proj_{\vec{CD}}\vec{AB}$$ in this image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gCA9b.png yield the red line I made there?

Comment: Yes. The resulting vector would be the same one as if you moved both to the origin, and then did the projection.